# Work with libgit2sharp to retrieve only the latest revision of a specific branch

Tags: libgit2sharp

Consider the following scenario:
Some content (e.g. a web-site) is under git repository having several branches like master (for dev), qa and prod.
A .net application (e.g. some cloud service) needs to have always the latest version of one specific branch (e.g. prod). There is no need to fetch full repository, only HEAD of this branch (git clone -b <branch> --depth=1 <remote_repo_url> --single-branch) and perform consequent updates.

How would you implement such scenario with **libgit2sharp** library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning only a truncated portion of the history from a repository (ie. shallow cloning) is not supported by LibGit2Sharp yet.

You can subscribe to **[issue #229](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/229)** to be notified of future progress.

Comment: is it now supported?

Comment: The issue has been moved to https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3058
and it's still not supported.