# LibGit2Sharp Getting the last version of a remote repository

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I want to track a project that uses git in my winforms project. I don't want to clone the full repository and the full history, I just want the latest version, and I want to be able to update to new revisions from the remote project.

I have tried this

```
co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = userName, Password = passWord };

        Repository.Clone("Git/repo", @tmpRepoFolder, co);
```

, but this creates a copy of the entire repository (huge file size), and tracking changes makes the disk space even bigger (100mb of files now takes up over 2gb).

I don't need the history and i don't need the tags. I just want the latest version .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Work with libgit2sharp to retrieve only the latest revision of a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037499/work-with-libgit2sharp-to-retrieve-only-the-latest-revision-of-a-specific-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want a **shallow** clone (the equivalent of the git clone --depth command) which is not actually supported, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/229) for that

As an alternative you can launch a Process which do what you want using the git application.

Here an example:

```
using(System.Diagnostics.Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe",
        Arguments = "clone http://username:password@path/to/repo.git"  + " --depth 1"                
    };

    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there's any other option to do a clone --depth hard coded in a c# code . creating a child process to do it or any other option . Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @sahar04 Added an example